# Firestore query either by phrase/string in document ID or contents of array in document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to find a way to find all documents in a collection, whose ID contains a certain string or by comparing their array with another array.

Basically I have a DB structure of products like:

```
computers_laptops_macbook-pro: { ...someData, categories: ["computers", "laptops"] }
```

And I am sending to my Cloud Function an array of categories: `["computers", "laptops"]`.

Is there a way I can either search for all documents whose IDs containt `computers_laptops` or whose `categories` contain both `"computers" and "laptops"`?

I tried `await marketplace_products_ref.where("categories", "array-contains", categories_array).get()` but doesnt find anything, even tho it should (if I am understanding its purpose correctly).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reviewing the documentation for [array membership queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership).  `array-contains` only finds a single value within an array.  If you have a multiple values to check for, you should instead use an `array-contains-any` query instead.

```
marketplace_products_ref
    .where("categories", "array-contains-any", categories_array)
```

Comment: The problem is that I need all of the values in categories_array to also be in product `categories`. But `categories` can have more than just whats in `categories_array `

Comment: OK.  Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: Not yet, I found a simpler way. I realized I only need to check for the lowest most category (hierarchically) and so I only need to check that the array contains that one value so I could use `"array-contains"` afteral. But thank you for the suggestion!